# Spring Mvc submit/delete checked (selected) records from table

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm trying to submit selected items from a table and moake some modifications on them but I couldn't get it work.

MyObject.java

```
public class MyObject{
    boolean checkControl = true; //default true
    private String name;
    private String code; 

    //getters & setters
}
```

MyObjectForm.java

```
public class MyObjectForm {
    private List<MyObject> myList;

    public List<MyObject> getMyList() {
        return myList;
    }

    public void setMyList(List<MyObject> myList) {
        this.myList= myList;
    }
}
```

list-myObjects.jsp

```
<form:form action="submitList" method="post" modelAttribute="myObjectForm">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <c:forEach items="${myObjectForm.myList}" var="row" varStatus="status">
        <tr>
                <td>
                    <spring:bind path="myList[${status.index}].checkControl">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="<c:out value="${status.value}"/>" name="isChecked" <c:if test="${row.checkControl}"> checked="checked" </c:if> />
                    </spring:bind>
                    </td>
                    <td>${row.name}</td>
                    <td>${row.code}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>  
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form:form>
```

And the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/submitList", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String save(@ModelAttribute("myObjectForm") MyObjectForm myObjectForm, Model model) {

    List<MyObject> selectedtList = myObjectForm.getMyList(); //returns null

    if (selectedtList == null) {
        System.out.println("no objects selected");
    }
    else {
        //Make some computation
    }
    model.addAttribute("resultArray", selectedtList);

    return "display-items";
}
```

Comment: _I couldn't get it work._ What did you get it to do? Errors?

Comment: I just want to see the items I've selected, on the page display items. than maybe I'll be able to make computations or modifications on selected objects.

Comment: Please explain your expected results and actual results.

Comment: selectedtList returns null in my controller. I can't get selected items in the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a binding issue. Have you tried using Spring's `<form:checkbox>` tag rather than `<spring:bind>`? It will automatically generate the checkbox attributes as well as adding a hidden field that Spring uses to determine whether the checkbox is 'on' or 'off'.

```
<form:form action="submitList" method="post" modelAttribute="myObjectForm">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <c:forEach items="${myObjectForm.myList}" var="row" varStatus="status">
        <tr>
                <td>
                    <form:checkbox path="myList[${status.index}].checkControl"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>${row.name}</td>
                    <td>${row.code}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>  
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Some users asked me to explain this in more detail by email. So I decided to submit it here, Hope this helps.

---

I'm using spring annotations, to do the job. here is what I did to process selected checkboxes,

I have a java entity class which includes a boolean value for the checkbox, for example a Person class

```
// Person.java
class Person {
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  private boolean check;

  //here goes getters and setters
}
```

than I have a form object in java, which contains a list of Person

```
//PersonForm.java
class PersonForm {
  private List<Person> personList;

  //getters and setters here
}
```

in my case, there are two jsp pages, the first one lists items, with checkboxes, and the second one lists selected items.

the first jsp file is list.jsp

//list.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="datatables" uri="http://github.com/dandelion/datatables"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

....

<body>

<form:form action="sent-list" method="post" modelAttribute="personForm">
        <table id="item-list" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead class="dataTableHeader">
                <tr>
                    <th width="10%" style="text-align:center">
                                     CheckBox
                    </th>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <c:forEach items="${personForm.personList}" var="listItem" varStatus="status">
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:center">
                        <form:checkbox path="listItem[${status.index}].check"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>${listItem.id} <form:hidden path="listItem[${status.index}].id"/></td>
                    <td>${listItem.name} <form:hidden path="listItem[${status.index}].name"/></td>          
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
        </table>  
         <button class="btn btn-large btn-success pull-right" type="submit">POST</button>
    </form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

the second jsp file is as follows

//sent-list.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="datatables" uri="http://github.com/dandelion/datatables"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
.....

<body>
<form:form action="#" method="post" modelAttribute="personForm">
        <table id="item-list" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead class="dataTableHeader">
                <tr>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <c:forEach items="${resultList}" var="personItem" varStatus="status">
                <tr>
                    <td>${personItem.id}</td>
                    <td>${personItem.name}</td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
        </table>  
    </form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

and finally there is a controller, which makes the computation

```
//PersonController.java
@Controller
class PersonController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/sent-list", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String save(@ModelAttribute("personForm") PersonForm personForm, Model model){ 
      for(Person personItem : personForm.getPersonList){
         //make some computation here
      }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: How are you adding the 'PersonForm' object to the ModelAndValue? Could you post the Controller method that populates the form model object initially?